# Date of last day of week in Firebird 3

Tags: sql, date, firebird

This is a date of first day of week (monday) in Firebird 3:

```
DATEADD(DAY, (EXTRACT(WEEKDAY FROM D - 1) * -1), D)
```

And how to get the date of the last day of the week (Sunday)?

In Firebird: Mon = 1, Tues = 2, ... Sun = 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ISO-8601 weeks, where Monday is the first day of the week, you can also determine Monday using:

```
dateadd(day, 0 - mod(extract(weekday FROM d) + 6, 7), d)
```

The use of `mod(extract(weekdays from d) + 6, 7)` will make Monday 0, Tuesday 1, etc and Sunday 6 to make the calculations easier.

You can then determine Sunday using:

```
dateadd(day, 6 - mod(extract(weekday FROM d) + 6, 7), d)
```

You can easily derive other days of the week this way (eg use `1 - mod(extract(weekday FROM d) + 6, 7)` for Tuesday, etc.

On the other hand, if Sunday is the first day of the week (eg as in the US), you can use:

```
dateadd(day, 0 - extract(weekday from d), d)
```

and for Monday

```
dateadd(day, 1 - extract(weekday from d), d)
```

Comment: SELECT
  DATEADD(DAY, 0 - MOD(EXTRACT(WEEKDAY FROM DATE '2020-01-12') + 6, 7), DATE '2020-01-12')
FROM RDB$DATABASE

Why your code return 6/01/2020? It is wrong.

Comment: @Akella225 I'm assuming the ISO-8601 standard where Monday is the first day of the week, and in ISO-8601, Monday 2020-01-06 and Sunday 2020-01-12 are in the same week. If you're looking for an answer for locales where Sunday is the first day of the week, see the second part of my answer: `dateadd(day, 1 - extract(weekday from d), d)`

Comment: i need last day of week - sunday 06/01/2020 or 12/01/2020 or 19/01/2020

Comment: Today is 2020-01-06 and that is a **Monday**. My answer first describes an alternative way to derive Monday, and **then** gives you a way to derive Sunday (using `dateadd(day, 6 - mod(extract(weekday FROM d) + 6, 7), d)`. The code for Sunday is the second code example, not the first.

Comment: SORY,  i need last day of week - sunday 05/01/2020 or 12/01/2020 or 19/01/2020

Comment: And that is `dateadd(day, 6 - mod(extract(weekday FROM d) + 6, 7), d)`, which for today (Monday 2020-01-06) will yield Sunday 2020-01-12.

Comment: es, thank you very much, this code works:

select   DATEADD(DAY, 6 - MOD(EXTRACT(WEEKDAY FROM DATE '2020-01-12') + 6, 7), DATE '2020-01-12') as ldow1